# Enter data from subform to table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have created a subform in 2013 version MS Access. I am able to insert the numbers from the form, but I am not able insert text string and duplicate line items. How to insert text strings and duplicate entries?

Comment: How did you try to insert text values?

Comment: @Sergey S I have selected string in combo box and used "insert into function"

Comment: @Sergey S, when I tried to enter string I encountered with run time error 3061

Answer (score 0):

If you use for inserting SQL or any parts of SQL in where clause for filters, DLookup-like functions etc, string variables should be enclosed in quotes:

```
strSQL="INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT '" & MyStringVar & "' as Field1, " & MyNumberVar & " as Field2"
```

Here used single quote, but also can be used double quote. In case of double quote is should be duplicated:

```
strSQL="INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT """ & MyStringVar & """ as Field1, " & MyNumberVar & " as Field2"
```

Comment: Dim strinsert As String
strinsert = "INSERT INTO tblKUT([Employee ID:], [Date:], [WRF#:], [Process:], [Subprocess:], [Issues:], [Re-solution:])" & _
"values(" & Me.Employee_ID_ & "," & Me.Date_ & "," & Me.WRF__ & "," & Me.Process_ & "," & Me.Subprocess_ & "," & Me.Issues_ & "," & Me.Re_solution_ & ")"

Comment: this code I have used, please tell me if any change is required

Comment: Determine which fields declared as Text in table tblKUT and enclose the corresponding variables in single quotes.

Comment: S.I tried your answer but same error and here employee ID: and date: only number all others are text

Comment: Error 3061 means, that the query expects more parameters than you provided. In your case there are no parameters in the query at all, it means that one or more column names in query is wrong. Names [Employee ID:], [Date:], [WRF#:], [Process:], [Subprocess:], [Issues:], [Re-solution:] should be exactly the same as in table definition, I suspect you added extra ":", check this. I recommend to create insert query in query builder first, copy SQL to VBA editor and replace values by variables.